# Kineticjs and hammerjs: Update Mouseposition correctly when stage was dragged

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, hammer.js

So, I have a draggable Stage and I add new Shapes (doubleclick / -tap) to it. Now my problem is, when I drag the stage and create some new objects after it, my objects are created on the wrong position at the stage. Here's my code-so-far (excerpt):

```
$('#toolbox_container').hammer().on('doubletap', function(e) {
        //console.log('x:' + e.gesture.center.pageX + ' y: ' + e.gesture.center.pageY);
        var xPos = e.gesture.center.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var yPos = e.gesture.center.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        // call addnode with position of tap/mouse
        addNode(xPos, yPos);
    });
```

Before adding more lines here, I made this simplified jsfiddle to show what's the problem. Just double-click (/tap) on the stage. Then drag the stage. Then again, doubleclick => wrong position: http://jsfiddle.net/4vfBY/7/

It would be great if someone could help me out here. I think my problem is in defining the xPos and yPos wrong, but I have no better Idea on how to do it.

Best regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, got it working now. All I had to do was getting the X- and Y-coordinates from the stage after dragging and add them zo my xPos / yPos like this:

```
$('#toolbox_container').hammer().on('doubletap', function (e) {
    stageX = stage.getX();
    stageY = stage.getY();
    var xPos = e.gesture.center.pageX - this.offsetLeft - stageX; //apply stageX
    var yPos = e.gesture.center.pageY - this.offsetTop - stageY; //apply stageY
    // call addnode with position of tap/mouse
    addNode(xPos, yPos);
});
```

You can see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/s9PAD/1/